Frontier: Transaction would exhaust the block limits
I am testing a parachain with Frontier included: Frontier Parachain Template. But when I am trying to deploy a smart contract following the steps in the Substrate Documentation: Access EVM accounts, I am getting the following error:
1010: Invalid Transaction: Transaction would exhaust the block limits

I know this template is not in the latest version, but what can be causing the issue?

Did you try to modify this https://github.com/paritytech/frontier-parachain-template/blob/ac10a6a534ea3a6e8f3a433f6ec1e08a7c8b76db/runtime/src/lib.rs#L738?

What values you recomend using?

We hardcode this. https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/351f328d4745f67aa539d0f6e2184ea576e9b886/runtime/darwinia/src/pallets/evm.rs#L28
